# Связка opencart + 1С + Robokassa

Tags: opencart, 1с

Привет.

Нужна вот такая связка opencart + 1С + Robokassa. Делать буду впервые. Подскажите, какую версию `opencart` лучше выбрать, чтоб потом не было траблов? Возможно, кто-то уже ходил этой тропой. Буду признателен, если расскажите, какие модули или плагины использовали.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Robokassa версия OpenCart не критичен.
Для настройки синхронизации с 1С версии платформы 8.2 или 8.3 и конфигурации Управление торговлей 10 или 11 серии выберите  версию ветки 1.5.*, лучше русифицированную ocStore.

Answer (score 0):

Для синхронизации с 1С используйте вот этот модуль https://github.com/zenwalker/opencart-exchange1c.
Других не существует. Версия OpenCart обязательно ocStore не ниже версии 1.5.х.
Скажу сразу, синхронизация работает только при прямых рук и понимании того что делаешь.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы не рекомендовал сейчас использовать опенкарт 1.5, т.к. он прилично отличается от всей ветки 2. В дальнейшем вы захотите использовать ещё расширений, неотвратимо наставите vqmod и ocmod плюшек, что планомерно приведёт к конфликтам в системе, проблемам с кешами и постоянным обращениями к разрабам на предмет перепила. Опять же, многие (качественные) расширения используют систему Евентов, коей в 1.5 просто нет. 
Берите сразу любой 2.x и чем новее тем лучше, система развивается и поддерживается. 
По поводу 1с, на личном опыте - самая стабильная система была у одного заказчика, где в опенкарт не ставили никаких расширений подключающих 1с, но со стороны 1с один раз была разработана подвязка по api к магазину. Делалось это именно разрабом 1с. Работала она на ура и никак не зависело от магазина. 
По интеркассе товарищи ответили вам совершенно справедливо - ищите модуль, покупайте, ставьте, юзайте. Только смотрите на отзывы и количество скачиваний. Лучше будет, если кто-то уже заюзал некий модуль и порекомендовал вам. 
Удачи.
З.ы. и упаси вас все, кто упасает, поставить ocStore русская сборка.